# Displaying the urgency of a package update

Tags: apt, package-management

With the recent kernel upgrades and the accompanying `*** System restart required ***` I've started to wonder how to more clearly state the status.

I understand the packages requiring reboot exist within `/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs`.  And (although not supported), `apt` can be ran from the command line to check the changelog for the urgency.

Is there an existing tool that checks what updates require a reboot and why?

Comment: I think the reason "system restart required" occurs is when packages  have downloaded the new files but cant install the executables or shared objects (libraries) files because the current version is in active use - and cant be swapped out - in situ. The most notable example of this is the kernel. As to how to check what packages need reboot have you tried `cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs` ?

Comment: Without a doubt, @the_velour_fog.  If my option is to create a script to check the file, then grep changelog for each package, then that is what I'll do.  I was checking for an existing solution.  The information is there, I was just curious if something exists already.